# Miracast over Infrastructure Validation and Troubleshooting

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface, miracast

I'm looking for some assistance with troubleshooting Miracast over Infrastructure. Specifically, validation that it's even working. From what I understand using it is supposed to be seemless and not any different than the typical Miracast.

The only problem being is how exactly do I verify that it's working? I don't see any indicators that it's doing over Infrastructure. That's one of the first things I want to check or understand, from a visibility standpoint how would I be able to check? If it's not clearly visible, is there a way to dig in and maybe run some commands to validate that it's actually doing it?

I've followed the guide listed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure

The devices that I'm testing with are on the same network, and there's no firewalling between them. The only thing that may be causing issues is that they are both on separate domains. This is between a Lenovo T460s Laptop running Windows 10 1803 and a Microsoft Surface Hub device running the latest OS as of Nov 2018, which should be fully up to date as of this posting.

I couldn't find much documentation on the subject. It would be awesome if there was a tool you could run to test to see Miracast over Infrastructure compatibility and maybe what's failing or preventing it from happening.

The reason I'm troubleshooting this is due to performance issues, and also just a way to validate and understand that it's working as intended (or fix it if it isn't working).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was as follows:

Our surface hubs are connected via a wired link.

We tested Miracast over Infrastructure by using a device connected to the same LAN (diff VLAN but same network) via WiFi and then projecting to the Hub and checking in control panel > Network adapters on our sending device to see if an additional wireless adapter appeared or not. It didnt which proved the transmission of data was across the existing network connection and not direct Peer to Peer WiFi.

We did the same test and removed the Surface hubs wired link and on the sending device we then saw the additional wireless adapter appear for the direct WiFi connection when presenting.